# xsl truncate a decimal

Tags: xslt, decimal

I have an xml file with an xsl that I am trying to change the way the numbers are displayed.  In the xml all the numbers are in the format 00:12:34

I need to remove the first 2 zeros and the colon and just display 12:34

I am not sure if I use a substring or a decimal format.  I am pretty new to this so any help would be marvellous.

code in the xsl is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
        <table class="albumTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">    
            <xsl:for-each select="track">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="duration"/></td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is simple:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(duration, ':')" />
```

See: [`substring-after()` in the W3C XPath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-substring-after).

---

This is a little more defensive (for the case that the "hours" part is unexpectedly not `'00:'`):

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="substring(duration, 1, 3) = '00:')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(duration, ':')" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="duration" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```